# Analyzing Crash Dump of Windows Service with SEHException

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, windbg, crash-dumps

I have a production windows service written in C# against the .NET Framework 4.0 that is crashing intermittently about once a day.  The system adminstrator at the remote site where the service is running extracted a dump file when the latest crash ocurred.  Analysis in windbg reveals that the one of the threads threw an SEHException:

```
                                       PreEmptive   GC Alloc                Lock
       ID  OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC           Context       Domain   Count APT Exception
  22    c   cdc 051c2600   1009220 Enabled  0f6af244:0f6b04d4 0054b9e0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker) System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0f43a964)
```

The stack from that thread is as follows:

```
ChildEBP RetAddr  
091ee930 71fb28ca clr!JIT_Dbl2IntSSE2+0x6
091ee954 71fb239a mscorlib_ni+0x2728ca
091ee9ac 71fb2299 mscorlib_ni+0x27239a
091ee9c4 738e21db mscorlib_ni+0x272299
091ee9d4 73904a2a clr!CallDescrWorker+0x33
091eea50 73904bcc clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+0x8e
091eeb94 73904c01 clr!MethodDesc::CallDescr+0x194
091eebb0 73969c29 clr!MethodDesc::CallTargetWorker+0x21
091eec90 73995c05 clr!QueueUserWorkItemManagedCallback+0x4b
091eeca4 73995c87 clr!Thread::DoExtraWorkForFinalizer+0x114
091eed54 73995d42 clr!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x101
091eedb4 73995dd9 clr!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x399
091eedd8 73a656d5 clr!Thread::ShouldChangeAbortToUnload+0x43a
091eedf0 73969b67 clr!ManagedThreadBase::ThreadPool+0x15
091eeebc 73a6525f clr!ManagedPerAppDomainTPCount::DispatchWorkItem+0xe6
091eef2c 73a66ac5 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::NewWorkerThreadStart+0x20b
091eef94 73995a08 clr!ThreadpoolMgr::WorkerThreadStart+0x3d1
091efab8 7679eccb clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+0x4b
091efac4 7715d24d kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
091efb04 7715d45f ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x23
091efb1c 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

The data embedded within the SEHException is as follows:

```
ClassName:  System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException
  Message:  External component has thrown an exception.
  HResult:  -2147467259
ErrorCode:  -1073741132
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing this or what additional analysis can be done?

Comment: You've got unmanaged code in the process that changes the floating processor's control register.

Answer (score 0):

When you get such errors, convert the codes in Hex format, which is

```
HRESULT 80004005
Error Code C00002B4
```

Google searches are much better then.

> 80004005 is E_FAIL, a very generic error
>
> C00002B4 seems to be EXCEPTION_FLOAT_MULTIPLE_FAULTS

If you use a C++ component and specify the */fp:strict* or */fp:except* compiler switch, this is not compatible with .NET any more. See [Specify Floating Point behavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7s85ffb.aspx) at Microsoft. .NET likes floating point exceptions to be masked.

You can try fixing this by declaring

```
[DllImport("msvcr110.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int _controlfp(int n, int mask)
```

and resetting the floating point behavior after you called the C++ code:

```
CallMyCppCodeHere();
_controlfp(0x9001f, 0xfffff);
```

Comment: I also remember that there's an MDA for this situation but I could not figure out the name of it at the moment.